# Storyboard global tint not shown properly in Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, assets, tint

I've defined a custom Color Set and applied it to global tint of the storyboard.

[As expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR8qD.png)

But after reopening the project it seems to be not found

[Not found screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZVf5.png)

That's not it yet. If i set global tint again to custom one it will work correctly (note here: git not showing any global tint change when setting it) until the next relaunch of the project, which will end up having same issue (2nd image)

Meanwhile, applied global tint works as expected in my app

Can anybody please explain the nature of this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: File a bug with Apple please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Xcode and is slated to be fixed in the [upcoming Xcode 11.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_release_notes/):

> Fixed an issue where named Global Tint colors weren’t properly unarchived during Interface Builder document loading resulting in incorrect Global Tint colors on subsequent document saves. (55158004) (FB7232333)